# Datetime Display In MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I need your help with datetime coversion. Inside my database I have date of comments entered like this:

```
  Datetime: 2012-05-08 14:44:53
```

How can I make it display something close to this

```
  May 15, 2012 2:44PM
```

Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DATE_FORMAT() is the answer to your question. **[It has several formats of date on this link](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%M %d, %Y %h:%i %p') as FormattedDate;
```

**[View The Output Here [SQLFiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07506/4)**

```
%M  Month name (January..December)
%d  Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
%h  Hour (01..12)
%i  Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%p  AM or PM
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strtotime()` to convert to a Unix timestamp.  You can then use `date()` to display the exact format you need.  Something like this:

```
$unix = strtotime($datetime);
echo date(F j Y g:iA, $unix);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use MySQL `DATE_FORMAT()` function.

Reference:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Example query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%a %d, %Y %l:%s%p') AS `myDate`;
```

Comment: I believe best practice says to separate data retrieval and data formatting, i.e. not using a SQL statement to format text.  Additionally, it's a lot easier to work with Unix timestamps rather than textual representations.

Comment: Maybe you're right, but I use to format dates with `date_format()` because I think it's faster than converting a `datetime` in Unix timestamp and then formatting. And I usually store all dates in `datetime` format because it's human readable; `timestamp` isn't.

Comment: Faster maybe, but still unnoticeable.  Personally I think adherence to best coding practice is preferable to a negligible performance advantage, if indeed it actually exists.